# Sync directly from Overleaf to Google Drive?

Tags: overleaf

I'm not sure this is right place to ask, but I have the following question.

Does Overleaf support editing synced files with Google Drive? I'm asking because when you sync (using the upload url in Overleaf), you can only view the synced file and not edit it. Is there a way to edit in Overleaf and have the file edited in Google Drive every time you compile?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please ask the staff of overleaf support for an answer, they should know ...

Comment: Okay thank you!

Comment: Should I delete the question or answer it myself if I'm provided with an answer?

Comment: You can add an selfanswer, that is welcome here!